# Spring AOP : Around aspect not working

Tags: java, spring, java-8, aop, spring-aop

I have one POJO class on which i have to hijack one of its method with my own logic.

POJO :

CustomerModel

```
package com.test.model;

public class CustomerModel
{
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String uid = "uid";
    public static final String DEFAULTB2BUNIT = "defaultB2BUnit";

    @Accessor(qualifier = "defaultB2BUnit", type = Accessor.Type.GETTER)
    public B2BUnitModel getDefaultB2BUnit()
    {
        return getPersistenceContext().getPropertyValue(DEFAULTB2BUNIT);
    }

    ...
}
```

This POJO class is auto generated and i can't change it. I want to use spring AOP feature to hijack getDefaultB2BUnit() method so that i can execute my logic to send correct B2BUnit.

So far i have done this ..

Aspect -

```
@Aspect
public class AccountSelectionAspect
{

@Resource
private AccountSelectionService accountSelectionService;

@Around("execution(* com.test.model.CustomerModel.getDefaultB2BUnit())")
public Object decideAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
{
    final B2BUnitModel account = accountSelectionService.getSelectedAccount();

    if (account == null)
    {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    return account;
}
}
```

spring.xml -

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean class="com.test.core.account.aspect.AccountSelectionAspect"/>
```

Now this aspect is not calling at all. Whenever there is a call made to fetch defaultB2BUnit, AOP is not hijacking the method.

```
final CustomerModel customer = currentUser;
B2BUnitModel defaultB2BUnit = customer.getDefaultB2BUnit();
```

Kindly suggest.

**Update -**

Can I not be able to use AOP on POJO class? What is the alternative then ?

Comment: Did you add the javaagent to JVM?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn ,  its working in other area of project.

Answer (score 1):

Spring AOP wont work with classes that are not spring beans. You need to use AspectJ for this. Read more:[spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop).

Comment: Can you please give some example ?

Comment: I cannot give you concrete example now, but since the spring docs suggest AspectJ for these cases (under the Spring AOP capabilities and goals section) I would start reading more about AspectJ for example:
https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting-aspectj.html

Comment: And i am not sure about the context and how CustomerModel is used but if you could create a bean of it that would also help.

Comment: thats the whole point. I can not create bean of it. I think i have to find out some other way of workaround and drop the idea of AOP

Comment: I thought that is the point but you did not state it so i mentioned anyways.

Comment: Do you always give up so easily? There is no need to "drop the idea of AOP". Activating [AspectJ via LTW in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) is nicely documented and a matter of minutes to configure if you are not too lazy to read the manual. RTFM, man!